# How to overlay a Qt Phonon video with an OpenGL scene?

Tags: qt, opengl, overlay, phonon

I want play a video with the Qt Phonon Player and overlay it with an OpenGL scene, so that the semitransparent OpenGL objects are above the video. I searched for hours but found no hints how to realize this. This Proof of Concept from Intel describes what I am looking for.

http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IEGD/324707.pdf

How can this be realized? Which components are necessary for this?

Some posts which are similar to mine:

to clearify my intention here i found a picture what perfectly describes what i am looking for. This picture is from a Intel articel for a Hardware Feature of a Intel embedded graphic device (http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IEGD/324707.pdf)

here is a picture http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/33352,bildschirmfotoGURGI.png

Could or better how could this effect be inplemented on LinuxOS? With compiz+opengl+qt ?

---

to clearify my intention here i found a picture what perfectly describes what i am looking for. This picture is from a Intel articel for a Hardware Feature of a Intel embedded graphic device (http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IEGD/324707.pdf)

here is a picture http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/33352,bildschirmfotoGURGI.png

Could or better how could this effect be inplemented on LinuxOS? With compiz+opengl+qt ?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you are attempting

Comment: this code is what i want to write ;) playing a video with phonon player and show on top a easy opengl scene like with a cube

Comment: sry I didn't write code for overlay yet because i read severeal questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803209/transparency-of-qdeclarativeview-containing-qml-on-top-of-a-qwidget-playing-a-vi (demotivating) so is it possible anyway ?

Comment: Hello, this document describes my idea http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=intel%20frambuffer%20overlaz&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.intel.com%2Fembedded%2Fsoftware%2FIEGD%2F324707.pdf&ei=n4JNUNf5CNDitQaQi4H4CA&usg=AFQjCNEkl9MDi8jWZD8WnvDVGa1GvmU4dw

Comment: to clearify my intention here i found a picture what perfectly describes what i am looking for. This picture is from a Intel articel for a Hardware Feature of a Intel embedded graphic device (http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IEGD/324707.pdf)

here is a picture http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/33352,bildschirmfotoGURGI.png

Could or better how could this effect be inplemented on LinuxOS? With compiz+opengl+qt ?

I really appreciate your comments !

Answer (score 0):

referring the post [Play a video with custom overlay graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473709/play-a-video-with-custom-overlay-graphics) it should be possible. But there the solution is descriped really shallow.